# Understand combination of array with math formula Variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, formula, array-formulas

I am new to **JavaScript** **arrays** and using **formulas** with components of an array hence I am finding it difficult to understand this code that I should apply in a web application. 
The **last line of code** specifically at `arrayNames[(Math.round(formulae))]`  is where I don't have a clue of what it means. Please help me devs.

```
<script>
let formulae = ( ((century/4) -2*century-1) + ((5*year/4)) + ((26*(month+1)/10))+day ) % 7;
let arrayNames =["Akosua","Adwoa","Abenaa","Akua","Yaa","Afua","Ama"];
let newArrayNames = arrayNames[(Math.round(formulae))] ;
</script>
```

Comment: `formulae` is a float and it's  being rounded. In this case the rounded value is serving as an "index" to pick a value from `arrayNames`.

Comment: In last line , it is simply getting the item from the array using index which here is formulae value. For example , say formulae value is 3 ( suppose) , , then arrayNames[3] will return "Akua". Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thank you @Charleskimani . Hope you don't mind up-voting  the answer , if you understood.

Comment: Done bro, I had forgot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you compute some number, which is depends on the centure, year, month and day. They all stored in the variables centure, year, month and day. This number will be the index of your future array.

> let formulae = ( ((century/4) -2*century-1) + ((5*year/4)) + ((26*(month+1)/10))+day ) % 7;

Then you create this array:

> let arrayNames =["Akosua","Adwoa","Abenaa","Akua","Yaa","Afua","Ama"];

Finally, you just get element from the array. As you remember `formulae` is index of the needle element. So now, I hope, this string is obvious:

> let newArrayNames = arrayNames[(Math.round(formulae))] ;